# Azure MySQL Data-in Replication stored procedures missing

Tags: mysql, azure

I am trying to configure Azure Data in replication for MySQL database and unable to find the inbuilt Stored Procedures(SPs) in MySQL DBaaS that  facilitates the replication in Azure cloud eg: mysql.az_replication_change_master.  Do we manually create these SPs as I am unable to find the required SPs DDL in Azure documentation?

Comment: Can you try creating a user with the ReplicationAdmin role, to see if the sp's are added...

Comment: Thanks ! We have done that  but the issue was related to Pricing tier of the Azure DB - it is supported only in General Purpose or memory optimized tiers..SPs wont be appearing under basic pricing tier.